# Autocomplete not working in Visual Studio Code python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autocomplete

I know that there is a lot of similar questions of this, but none of them worked for me. My autocomplete feature in Visual Studio Code just stopped working.

[image]

I'm using python 3.7.4 from Anaconda3 distribution.

I've also installed the python extension.

Below is my `settings.json` content from Visual Studio Code:

**settings.json**

```
{
    "python.dataScience.sendSelectionToInteractiveWindow": true,
    "python.dataScience.askForKernelRestart": false,
    "editor.fontFamily": "Fira Code",
    "editor.fontLigatures": true,
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda3\\python.exe",
    "terminal.integrated.shell.windows": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe",
    "python.linting.enabled": false,
    "editor.tabCompletion": "on",
    "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
    "files.autoSaveDelay": 500,
    "python.formatting.provider": "black",
    "python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
    "python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
}
```

I've already tried to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio Code with no success and also same with Python extension...

Can't figure out what is the problem.

Appreciate any help.

---

**Update**

[image]

I just noticed that my python interpreter is not activating in conda environment. Could that be the problem? Shouldn't it be `Python 3.7.4 ('base':conda)` as showned at [Using Python environments in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)?

[image]

Comment: Is pandas installed in the root anaconda environment? If not, you need to change the pythonPath to use the anaconda environment that pandas is installed in.

Comment: is your file saved? try saving the file first then try

Comment: Yes, it's installed in the root anaconda environment

Comment: @TenaciousB, yes. I saved my file before. Didn't work either.

Comment: How did you select the environment? It should mention conda if you selected a conda environment for which you specified a Python version from the "Select Interpreter" command. See [the docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments) for more details.